# Flex/Bison: Error when building a sample project to generate Cpp

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to generate Cpp (not C) using flex and bison. I got a sample code from GitHub (https://github.com/ezaquarii/bison-flex-cpp-example) and trying to build it.

Here is Makefile content

```
all:
    flex -o scanner.cpp scanner.l
    bison -o parser.cpp parser.y
    g++ -g main.cpp scanner.cpp parser.cpp interpreter.cpp command.cpp -o a.out

clean:
    rm -rf scanner.cpp
    rm -rf parser.cpp parser.hpp location.hh position.hh stack.hh
    rm -rf a.out
```

When I run command **make**, I get the following error

```
flex -o scanner.cpp scanner.l
bison -o parser.cpp parser.y
"parser.y", line 29: junk after `%%' in definition section
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault
```

Here is my bison version (Linux OS)

```
bison --version
bison++ Version 1.21.9-1, adapted from GNU bison by coetmeur@icdc.fr
Maintained by Magnus Ekdahl <magnus@debian.org>
```

May someone tell me what is going wrong ?

Comment: There's a problem on line 27 of parser.y. That has nothing to do with your Makefile. It's probably because your parser.y file is using a recent bison extension, not supported by bison++.

Comment: The code you use is written for "normal" GNU bison (version greater than 3) not for bison++, which is a fork. AFAIK this fork is dead.

bison --version should give something like: "bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4 [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my bison version.

```
bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

@user6556709, thanks for the fix.